# How to compile C++ for the same preprocesor variable

Tags: c++, bash, compiler-errors, macros, c-preprocessor

In main.c ++ I have several preprocessor variables defined.

```
#ifndef FIRST
#define FIRST "./path/for/output/files"
#endif
#ifndef SECOND
#define SECOND 0.0125 
#endif
#ifndef THIRD
#define THIRD "./input_file.mesh"
#endif
```

I have to compile this .cpp by varying the three preprocessor macros. To do this, I tried to make a bash file with a for loop to vary the values that these macros took, that is:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in  *.mesh
do
  g++ -Ofast -fopenmp main.cpp eig3.cpp vema.cpp -o main10 -DFIRST=\"\.\/$i\" -DSECOND=0.0125 -DTHIRD=\'\"\.\/$i\"\'
done
```

This loop constantly reports error, it does not recognize the input file and neither does the output folder. I imagine that I am making many mistakes, I am new to C ++ and I am still a bit lost.

I would like to know if there is any possibility to compile this code with many different values for each parameter. Thank you!

Comment: `main.cpp` ≠ `main.c++`.

Comment: What errors are you actually seeing? Please [edit] your question and paste the actual messages into your question.

Comment: On a related note, you appear to be reinventing [Makefiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile), this is a good opportunity to read up on them! Googling "C++ Makefile tutorial" should get you started. To help with your actual problem, as Ken said, we need the error message.

Comment: Why don't you pass these as parameters to your program instead? It looks like something that's more convenient to define when running the program than during compilation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **really** don't want to change the program all that much, compile it once as follows:

```
g++ -Ofast -fopenmp main.cpp eig3.cpp vema.cpp -o main10 -DFIRST='getenv("OUTPUT")' -DSECOND=0.0125 -DTHIRD='getenv("INPUT")'
```

And call it as follows:

```
for i in *.mesh; do
  INPUT=./$i OUTPUT=./path/for/output/files ./main10 
done
```